# Flutter TextField inputFormatters not wokring with my custom regex

Tags: regex, flutter, dart, textfield

I want to allow this kind of input to my text field:

```
123
*123#
*123*4#
```

so I created and tested `RegExr` website this regex:

`\**\d+\**\d+\#?`

but when i try to type nothing is typed in the text field

code of using:

```
     ...

     keyboardType = TextInputType.phone;

     // to allow digits with asterik and hash
     final regex = RegExp(r'\**\d+\**\d+\#?');

     inputFormatters = [FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(regex)];

     return TextField(
      ...
      keyboardType: keyboardType,
      inputFormatters: inputFormatters,
     );
```

Comment: Try `r'^\**\d+\**\d+\#?$'`

Comment: same doesn't work

Comment: What if you try `^(?!(?:.*\*[*#]|\d*#$))\*?\d*\*?\d*#?$` https://regex101.com/r/lGd4Vc/1

Comment: Try `^\*?(?:\d+\*?(?:\d+#?)?)?$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/ABfKQJ/1)).

Comment: but then @WiktorStribiżew regex also worked and look much simpler and easy to understand so I use that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you also want to match a variation with a single digit like `*1#` you might use a negative lookahead excluding what can not be present:

```
^(?!.*\*[*#]|\d*#$)[*\d]*#?$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what to the right is not

  - `.*\*[*#]` Match either `**` or `*#`
  - `|` Or
  - `\d*#$` Match optional digits and `#` at the end of the string
- `)` Close lookahead
- `[*\d]*#?` Match optional `*` chars or digits and optional `#`
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l51U09/1).

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
^\*?(?:\d+\*?(?:\d+#?)?)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ABfKQJ/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\*?` - an optional `*` char
- `(?:\d+\*?(?:\d+#?)?)?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\d+` - one or more digits
  - `\*?` - an optional `*`
- `(?:\d+#?)?` - an optional sequence of one or more digits and an optional `#` char
- `$` - end of string.